# LimeJS vs CreateJS for game development

Tags: easeljs, createjs, limejs

I want to start developing HTML5/JS games. And I see these 2 frameworks LimeJS and CreateJS & EaselJS. Which one is better? Does anyone have experience with these 2 frameworks? And what about the documentation?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, I experienced both unfortunately.

[Limejs](http://www.limejs.com/) :

- 1 . You should have python installed to compile and run the code.
- 2 .    You should manually use other javascripts inorder to preload
  all the    assets before the game gets start or else there will be
  chance to    slower the game animations.
- 3 . The compiled code is non    human    readable so that your code
  cannot be understandable to third    party    users. The compilation
  is done using python
- 4 . Issue with    audio on    different browsers    in different
  levels.
- 5 . No other    resources other    than    [Developers

  API](http://limejs.digitalfruit.ee/docs/)

[CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/CreateJS)

- 1 . You can directly use javascript for html and run.
- 2 . CreateJS    itself haves PreLoadJS,TweenJs,EaselJS,SoundJS so you
  can render    loaders and audio easily
- 3 . No compilation less    security in case of    javascript file
- 4 .    You will be using soundjs    for loading audio.
- 5 .    Has    their own    API for each    Tween,Easel,Sound and
  Preload

`Last and Finally compare to LimeJs, Many developers use Createjs for developing games` including me.

Answer (score 9):

The [Breakouts](http://city41.github.com/breakouts/) project might help.  It's sort of like TodoMVC in that they take a simple game of Breakout and implement it in different frameworks.

It covers Easel/CreateJS, LimeJS and 10 other popular frameworks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using EaselJS and personally I'm very happy with it, it's activly developed and also supported by Adobe and Microsoft.
As a possible alternative you could take a look at http://kineticjs.com

If you are interested in getting started with EaselJS you can take a look at my tutorial-series: http://indiegamr.com/retro-style-plattform-runner-game-for-mobile-with-easeljs-part-1/
(They are slightly out of date, as they where written for the previous verison of EaselJS, but still do work with the current version)

Comment: Nice tutorial.  I notice that it's from July.  Has the API changed much since you wrote this or is it still applicable?

Comment: Yes it has, but the only major change is the handling of Events now. But the old methods of event-handling are still working. I'm currently working on an extended, follow up project to the tutorial. (But its not quite done yet)

Answer (score 4):

I've just started developing games with EaselJS, seems easy if you know JS at some level.
The lack of real world examples is a minus, but there are plenty of tutorials on basic usages of framework. And yeah, there is lots of good documentation on Easel on their website.
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/

Their SoundJS and TweenJS are also very impressive libraries, take a look at them ;)

Answer (score 3):

CreateJS is right tool to get started quickly. We are using HTML5 to create games with Javascript and HTML and that's why no reason to get involved with Python in LimeJS.

Comment: Do you happen to have any suggestion for resources?  The site is light and what's there seems very old.

Comment: Well they have documentation for each class (e.g; http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/). I think a good tutorial is enough to get started then you will be able to utilize the documentation by yourself.

Check this tutorial: http://www.atari.com/arcade/developers/building-atari-createjs

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for CreateJS got a huge update in February/2013, and there are a bunch of tutorials for EaselJS that can help get you started.